# accommodate vs humor

Tags: word-choice

> if you can humor/accommodate me, I would really appreciate it

so in the sentence above, do the use of both 'humor' and 'accommodate' sound natural in every day conversation. can people understand what I mean right away?

and also, my understanding of the words is that 'humor' means to 'tolerate my condition', and 'accommodate' is more on the side of 'work around / provide extra effort or help to suit my need'?

and what about 'humor me' by itself, is it a idiom?

how do you use them yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accommodate someone is to make adjustments that help that person in some meaningful way. It is a neutral expression.

To humor someone is to accommodate them in a way that, to you, may seem unusual, eccentric, or even unreasonable.

When someone says "humor me" they are attempting to override any protestations of this latter behavior. It is the equivalent of saying, "Yeah, maybe I'm being unreasonable or maybe you don't understand why I would ask this favor, but please do it anyway."

Comment: what do you mean by "it is a neutral expression"? as in neither derogatory nor complimentary?

Comment: I mean that *accommodate me* does not bear the same subjective overtones of *humor me*.

Answer (score 0):

The two are almost, but not quite, synonymous.

> I know my request for an extra seat for my double-bass is unusual, but if you could accommodate me...

vs

> I know you don't believe I just saw a flying saucer, but just for a minute, humour me...

One requires some actual expenditure of effort, the other merely a change of will.